# update a specific object inside an array of object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, laravel

I have the following document:

```
{
   _id: objectId("5aa7abb3c7dc133b0007e6e"),
   name: "first course",
   targets: Array
     0: Object
        id: "11111_rrrr",
        value: "test"
     1: Object
        id: "22222_rrrr",
        value: "hi"
}
```

so, I want to change the value of the array[i].
my solution is :

```
$update = array(
        'targets.$[].value' => "New Value"
    );

    $result = Course::where("_id", $course_id)->update($update);
```

it changes all the value of the array, how can I solve my problem??

Comment: Use `$update = array(
        'targets.0.value' => "New Value"
    );`

Comment: I have dashboard so, I  don't know any index in the array.
I need a dynamic way to iterate the array.

Comment: You said _so,  all I want to do is to change the value of the array[0]_

Comment: I'm sorry, I will change my question.

Comment: Dont be sorry. Its fine. So how do you identify the array. is it by id ?

Comment: yes, my document is like this :
 "_id" : ObjectId("5aa7abb3c7dc1c33b00076e6"),
        "name" : "first_coursetest",
        "caption" : "First Course",
        "targets" : [
                {
                        "id" : "1520937903756_",
                        "value" : "qqq",
                },
                {
                        "id" : "1521028321828_as",
                        "value" : "qqq",
                }
        ]

Comment: and I have target_id, but I can't make a condition between $target_id and id inside the array

Comment: Try `Course::raw()->findOneAndUpdate(
            ['_id' => $user_id, 'targets.id' => $target_id],
            ['$set' => ["targets.$.value" => "New Value"]]
        );`

Comment: @Veeram thanks, bro it works for me I was trying to use update not findoneandupdate so is there any place I can revise the pipeline stages for laravel jenssegers

Comment: Np. I'm not sure but try `$update = array(
        'targets.$.value' => "New Value"
    );$result = Course::where(['_id' => $user_id, 'targets.id' => $target_id])->update($update);`

Comment: Ok, my problem solved. Thank you very much for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
db.getCollection('TEST').update({"targets.id" : $course_id},{$set:{"targets.$.value" : "New Value"}})
```